# Unknown Path Foxx PUT service

Tags: arangodb

When I try PUTing my Foxx service in ArangoDB I get this error:

```
{
  "error": true,
  "code": 404,
  "errorNum": 404,
  "errorMessage": "unknown path '/_api/foxx/service?teardown=false&setup=true&legacy=false&mount=/upload&name=upload&version=1&development=true&manifest={%20%20%22engines%22:%20{%20%20%20%20%22arangodb%22:%20%22^3.0.0%22%20%20},%20%20%22main%22:%20%22index.js%22,%20%20%22scripts%22:%20{%20%20%20%20%22setup%22:%20%22scripts/setup.js%22%20%20}}'"
}
```

This is a call from Postman and within Postman it is a copy/paste from a working call to an other server. That is why this confuses me.
Also, using the Web Interface, I can upload this fine.

What does this error message mean exactly?

Arango: 3.0.12
Log stays empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was probably a bug in Arango. I run CentOS7 and there is more than 1 (!!) repo at arangodb.com for CentOS7, also probably a bug. After reinstalling the repo for CentOS7 the software upgraded, completely destroyed SSL but the deployment is working now :)